# Need help to split string in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `"portal100common2055"`.

I would like to split this into two parts, where the second part should only contain numbers.

`"portal200511sbet104"` would become `"portal200511sbet"`, `"104"`

Can you please help me to achieve this?

Comment: If you only want the last four characters why not substring?

Comment: substring i can do but i dont know weather i can have only last 4 characters as numeric.it can be last 5 characters or 3 the below solution is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)(\\d+)$").matcher(args[0]);
    if( m.find() ) {
        String prefix = m.group(1);
        String digits = m.group(2);
        System.out.println("Prefix is \""+prefix+"\"");
        System.out.println("Trailing digits are \""+digits+"\"");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not match");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d+$)");
if (parts.length < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input does not end with numbers: " + input);
String head = parts[0];
String numericTail = parts[1];
```

This more elegant solution uses the *look behind* and *look ahead* features of regex.

Explanation:

- `(?<=\\D)` means at the current point, ensure the preceding characters ends with a non-digit (a non-digit is expressed as `\D`)
- `(?=\\d+$)` means t the current point, ensure that only digits are found to the end of the input (a digit is expressed as `\d`)

This will only the true at the desired point you want to divide the input